# Shoud i use Spacy Named Entity Recognition for this case?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I have a set of names, a fixed set of names which can extend up-to 50,000 names.

"John","Mike","Josh","Peter","Karl".

And I have a document, this document is dynamic. I need to find whether this document has
the predefined name or not ?

Is defining everything as a entity in spacy nlp the right way to do it ?

Comment: Can you post sample of the document that you want to find the matched names in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that your purpose is to look for known names (from a list) in a document.

It seems that Named Entity Recognition may not be useful to you.

Instead, a scalable approach to this problem can be Flashtext (https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext).

Answer (score 1):

> Is defining everything as a entity in spacy nlp the right way to do it ?

No. NER is based not on a huge set of values with a tag, but as data set of text samples that contain the value, the tag and the value position. In general, a machine learning model is then trained over the dataset, finding generalizations that can help tagging names in a document.

So you cannot just add these names to train the NER. You have to provide context.

What you could try is the following simple pipeline (considering these names are somewhat common):

1. Load the names into a set data structure.
2. Analyze the documents, sentence by sentence, using your chosen NLP library.
3. For each sentence, discover the Named Entities of type Person in it.
4. Check if each person is in the name set.